# IntelliJ Idea - debugging during evaluations like in Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea

As far as I remember, in Eclipse it was possible (while Java code debugging) to select some method for example and then click inspect and breakpoints in that method were catched. In Idea when I evaluate some method while debugging, it never catches the breakpoints inside. Only after i click play button then I go into that method. Is it possible in Idea?

Comment: That is also possible in IDEA.  something else seems amiss.

Comment: Wow I never knew this wasn't possible (I tried it and couldn't see a solution). Would love to see an answer to this.